# Update mysql table in vb.net using datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Hi guys I need help in updating the data on my datagridview. The Scenario is when I click the Search button it will query the appropriate data and display that I want to the datagridview. Then I want to update if their any changes or deleted data from datagridview then also update to my mysql table for new data or record whenever I click the Update Button. The problem is that when I click my search button the messagebox appears "The table contains no changes to save." this means there is no changes but i already change values in datagridview. Anyone could help me?
Here is for my search button code:

```
   Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sql As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = ("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=12345;database=dbsis3bkenth;")
            Try
                conn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT LName,FName,MI FROM tblsisterbrother where IDNoBrodSis = '" & cbIDNo.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Found.!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record Unfound.!")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching to database:error is:" & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    dr.Close()
    RemoveHandler DataGridView1.CellValidating, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValidating
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(ds, "tblsisterbrother")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    conn.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Here is the code for my update button:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    If dt.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("The table contains no changes to save.")
    Else
        Dim builder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = da.Update(dt)
        If rowsAffected = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No rows were affected by the save operation.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " rows were affected by the save operation.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Please help me guys to solve my problem :)

Comment: How do you not get confused with all those extra global object variables?  You have a DataTable declared for the form, then each procedure declares and creates new ones each time. **Use** the module level one, and you wont have to cast the DS to get at the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN page about GetChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k2552649%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets a copy of the DataTable that contains all changes made to it since it was loaded or AcceptChanges was last called.

Since you're declaring the DataTable and loading it only one time, it's working as expected.

To make it work like you want you'll have to use the CellEditEnd event, and call the GetChanges() method from DataGrid.DataSource, something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    Dim Changes As DataTable
    Changes = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: Shall I input that code to DataGridView1_CellEndEdit? and what next sir? in update button, is there any changes that to be made?

Comment: It would be a good idea to take a look in the documentation about DataGridView, it may be a little bit tricky getting it to work as you expect and understanding it's behaviors help a lot. Either way, the code I sent you will update the database after every edit. If you want to update everything at once when you click a button you just have to replace your lines "Dim dt" and "dt=" with mine "Dim Changes" and "Changes=".

Comment: Hello Sir, I can now successfully update, my problem for now is now that i can update with it when i clear the data that is display in my datagridview with a clear button then I search again it duplicates the data then clear again then when i search again it doubles the data again.. How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but seems like you need to clear the DataSource, or else it may duplicate the results. You have to add "DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing" to the Click event on the Clear button.